# Windows 10 IoT Keyboard Wedge

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Zebra TC70x and am looking for a keyboard wedge solution. I am needing to input any scanned barcode into a text field, but apparently, the barcode scanner will not function without being called.

Does anyone know of a way to use the barcode scanner as described above?

Comment: Do handheld barcode scanners for PC not already output keystrokes?  I guess I assumed that they did, and that they didn't use any "wedge" thing to convert to keystrokes.

Comment: The Zebra TC70x is a PDA style barcode scanner, with Windows 10 IoT on-board. Apparently, the Windows 10 IoT version requires an application to invoke the barcode scanners, otherwise it will not active. There is a Zebra Barcode Scanner app in the Microsoft Store, but it doesn't pass the data to other apps.

Comment: Not sure how to access the hardware, but there is a zxing.net library for reading barcodes once you do have the input.

Comment: Generally, wedges can be less useful on task-oriented devices like handhelds since users often need to set focus to the right input-box, and filter by symbology types.  Also wedging apps don't always handle larger string input from 2D barcodes they way you might expect. You may find the docs and samples at ['MS PointOfService barcode scanning and more'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/point-of-service), a path forward for more task-specific needs.